# Sony D2203 and google cardboard

Tags: google-cardboard, sony-xperia

I have a sony xperia E3 (D2203) I can build the demo for google cardboard and load the apk in the phone. When I open it it does starts, I see a menu with [reset] [recenter] [VR mode]
But the movement tracking is not working.

There is also a settings icon, when I click it leads to the cadboard app in google Play store. and In there I find out that my device is not compatible with it.

Can I work with this phone without this configuration app ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google Cardboard needs a built-in gyroscope to accurately track movements. Sony D2203 doesn't have this hardware, so it won't be much fun playing with Cardboard.

Comment: O.O I doesn't ? Lame phone ... Thanks for the info! I focused on the screen and it seamed Ok to me so I was surprised. Thanks!